# FHIR: date filter in smart on fhir search api

Tags: javascript, hl7-fhir, smart-on-fhir

I'm new to Smart on FHIR and Creating one demo application for training purpose using fhirclient.js. I need to get some specific vital information of patient like Temp, Weight and so for specified period of date (last 3 months).

```
smart.patient.api.search({
                    type: "Observation",            
                    query: {          
                      $sort: [
                          ["date",
                          "asc"]
                    ],
                    code: {
                      $or: ['http://loinc.org|8462-4',
                        'http://loinc.org|8480-6',
                        'http://loinc.org|55284-4',
                        'http://loinc.org|8310-5',
                        'http://loinc.org|3141-9',
                        'http://loinc.org|718-7']
                    }
                  }
                  }).then(results => {
```

Let me know how to include date filter in this search api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a mongo-like syntax sugar provided by `fhir.js`. It acts as an URL builder and the result FHIR URL might look like:

https://r3.smarthealthit.org/Observation?_sort:asc=date&code=http://loinc.org|8462-4,http://loinc.org|8480-6,http://loinc.org|55284-4,http://loinc.org|8310-5,http://loinc.org|3141-9,http://loinc.org|718-7

Latest versions of `fhirclient` does not come with `fhir.js` included. Nowadays we have things like `URLSearchParams` to help us achieve similar results. Using an up to date version of the `fhirclient` library, the code you are looking for could look like this:

```
const client = new FHIR.client("https://r3.smarthealthit.org");
const query = new URLSearchParams();
query.set("_sort", "date");
query.set("code", [
  'http://loinc.org|8462-4',
  'http://loinc.org|8480-6',
  'http://loinc.org|55284-4',
  'http://loinc.org|8310-5',
  'http://loinc.org|3141-9',
  'http://loinc.org|718-7'
].join(","));
query.set("date", "ge2013-03-14"); // after or equal to 2013-03-14
query.set("date", "le2019-03-14"); // before or equal to 2019-03-14
client.request("Observation?" + query).then(...)
```

Also see http://hl7.org/fhir/search.html#date for details about the `date` parameter syntax.

Comment: Thanks.. Resolved my problem. I'm just followed your hint and added date filter in the RestApi like below 
                        date:
                        {                            
                            $and: ['ge2014-10-03',
                                'le2019-03-14']
                        }